# junit array test considers two different arrays to be equal

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, junit4

Java 8 code.  I have two byte arrays, obviously different:

[image]

When I compare these via a junit test (junit 4.11) (`assertArrayEquals(orig, new);`) the test is returning success on Windows, but correctly reports a failure on Linux.

Why would this test think the arrays are the same?

Environment is latest intellij (13.1.6) and included junit (4.11).

Thanks!

Comment: Latest IntelliJ IDEA is 14.0.1 ;)

Comment: Well, it hasn't asked me to update yet, so I'm sticking with my original story.  ;)

Comment: Can you provide the source of the test case so I could run and analyze it on my side?

Comment: I cannot, really, as the arrays are generated by an external call, but it's really just taking one byte[16] array, passing that to a method (which performs some work on the data and returns a byte[16]), then comparing the results via the assertArrayEquals call.

Comment: Is there something running asynchronously in another Thread? What happens if you debug this on Windows and verify that the arrays differ before assertArrayEquals() is called? Was the array really different when running on Windows, i.e. is the dumped data that I can see in the question from Windows or from Linux?

Comment: I did a line by line stepthrough of the code (on windows, from where the illustrated data originates) and verified that the arrays are different before the call to assertArrayEquals().

Comment: Could you please post the test method?